# How to remove any previous program from Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a Arduino UNO and I want to remove the previously uploaded code....how to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the code?

Answer (score 4):

Just upload a new one. I frequently "blank" an arduino when I'm done with it by uploading "Blink.ino" from the examples included with the IDE. (The only reason I've had to remove old code is to avoid an issue where I might later wire up the Arduino in a way that is dangerously incompatible with the old code running on it.)

Comment: `examples/01.Basics/BareMinimum` would be even better, as it doesn't set pin 13 to OUTPUT. Which would be a problem if your next project has a button connected to pin 13, and you accidentally press the button before uploading new code.

Comment: @sniggerfardimungus can I upload the empty sketch that is present when we open the Arduino IDE? I mean ony the void setup and void loop one....

Answer (score 2):

Replacing your sketch with another doesn't actually "remove" the previous one. Is that really necessary? If you're trying to prevent the first one from executing, replacing it, as already suggested by @Juraj, is a simple and proper solution.

If you need to prevent anyone ever being able to read any part of the previous one, you'd need to load another sketch at least as large as the previous one so it over-writes all of it, or create and run a modified "bootloader" program that erases the parts of flash you wish to obscure.

(Your question doesn't address your reason for wanting to "remove" the sketch. I'm adding this for completeness; not because I think it's likely.)

Answer (score 1):

I got it. just upload blank code that is written when you start arduino ide.